# How does doGet() support bookmarks?

Tags: java, servlets

Reading below link , I could note that "doGet() allows bookmarks".

http://www.developersbook.com/servlets/interview-questions/servlets-interview-questions-faqs.php : search "It allows bookmarks"

Can anyone tell how and what is the use of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the parameters of `GET` request are contained in the url so when you are requesting for a resource using `GET` request, it can be formed using request URL itself.
Consider an example `www.somesite.com.somePage.jsp`. This generates a `GET` request because we are asking for a resource `somePage.jsp`.

- If you are asking for a resource, then it is the `GET` request.
- `GET` requests are used to retrieve data.
- any `GET` request calls the `doGet()` method of servlet
- `GET` requests are idempotent, i.e. calling the same resource again and again do not cause any side effects to the resources.
- Hence, a `GET` request can have bookmarks

**EDIT :-**

As suggested by Jerry Andrews, `POST` methods do not have the query data unlike `GET` requests to form the resource properly with the help of only url. Hence they are not bookmarked.

Comment: It might also help to know that the doPost() method implements POST requests--the URL itself doesn't contain any additional information, so a browser bookmark wouldn't contain everything you'd need to know to get to the same point on the site (and rightly so, since a POST's purpose is to deliver data to the site).

Answer (score 1):

It means that If you bookmark the URL of the servlet that has `doGet()` implemented, you could always get the same page again when you re-visit. This is very common when you have searches, link for products, news, etc.